# Build webrtc-android got invalid -march= option: `armv7-a'

Tags: webrtc

when I setup the envsetup.sh, install-build-deps.sh,and install-build-android-deps.sh. After this, I got invalid -march=option:`armv7-a`. Did I miss something ? How to solve this problem?

```
 [6/4674] CXX obj/webrtc/system_wrappers/source/metrics_default.metrics_default.o
FAILED: obj/webrtc/system_wrappers/source/metrics_default.metrics_default.o 
/home/whb/webrtc/webrtcAndroid/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MF obj/webrtc/system_wrappers/source/metrics_default.metrics_default.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNO_TCMALLOC -DDISABLE_NACL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=270823-1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_MEDIA_ROUTER=1 -DENABLE_BROWSER_CDMS -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_EXTERNAL_POPUP_MENU -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DUSE_BROWSER_SPELLCHECKER=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DVIDEO_HOLE=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DENABLE_WEBVR -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_REMOTE -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DWEBRTC_BUILD_LIBEVENT -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM_V7 -DWEBRTC_HAS_NEON -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DWEBRTC_ANDROID -DWEBRTC_INCLUDE_INTERNAL_AUDIO_DEVICE -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_OPENSSL_CERTS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DANDROID -D__GNU_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H -DANDROID_NDK_VERSION=r10e -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -Igen -I../.. -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wno-extra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -fno-builtin-cos -fno-builtin-sin -fno-builtin-cosf -fno-builtin-sinf -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -march=armv7-a -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fno-tree-sra -fno-caller-saves -Wno-psabi -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -g -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -finline-limit=64 --sysroot=../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//platforms/android-16/arch-arm -Os -g -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-abi -std=gnu++11 -Wno-narrowing -isystem../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include -isystem../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/libcxxabi/include -isystem../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//sources/android/support/include  -c ../../webrtc/system_wrappers/source/metrics_default.cc -o obj/webrtc/system_wrappers/source/metrics_default.metrics_default.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv7-a'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Does anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this Problem by Download a new NDK EDITION from Google! The NDK I used is in the webrtc/thirdparty/androidtool/, I don't know why this NDK is Error!